# My object code cannot be executed

Tags: gcc, executable

I compile my c code with gcc and it creates an obj code but when I tried to run it it gives cannot execute binary file error how can I solve this problem can you help me?

```
gcc -c virtualAddressManager.c -o vam

./vam.exe

cannot execute binary file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you creating an object file? If you want to create an executable, you shouldn't use the `-c` option.

Additionally, where did you get the `vam.exe` from? With the command you issued, you will get an output file called `vam` without the `.exe` part. You aren't working on Windows, are you?

To get an executable and run it, you should do

```
gcc virtualAddressManager.c -o vam
chmod +x vam
./vam
```

Comment: you should not need `chmod +x vam` It won't hurt but gcc will make `vam` executable by default.

Comment: No I am not working on Windows I have made a mistake here at vam.exe